# Preventing action in web application from being called twice (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to make sure an ASP.NET MVC action is not called twice (i.e. if the user clicks on a button twice in quick succession)?  On most of our screens, it's not a big deal if it happens ... but on a few it causes havoc (like paying people multiple times instead of just once).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could disable the submit button using javascript. For example with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(':submit, :image', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There was a recent thread about this (with Darin actually).

A combination of doing as he mentioned and implementing a [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) strategy covers most holes.

Comment: We use P-R-G on most pages, it's the jquery post/submit pages that were the problem (since the calls would go through asynchronously).  I'll try Darin's suggestion on these.